# ¿Por qué no puedo ver ofertas de trabajo en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte

Estoy inscrito a Stack Overflow en inglés y en español con diferentes cuentas. En la de inglés puedo ver ofertas de trabajo, pero en la de español no.

¿Es algo de mi configuración o el sitio en español no tiene esa funcionalidad?

Comment: La sección de /Jobs solo está disponible para el sitio de [so], no para [es.so]. La página de [Developer Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) incluye ofertas de todo el mundo, incluyendo países de habla hispana pero la información siempre aparecerá en inglés ;)