# Está permitido postear propuestas laborales en este sitio?

Tags: discusión, ofertas-de-empleo

Hay algún lugar del sitio en el que se puedan postear propuestas laborales?

Answer (score 8):

Las propuestas laborales que aparecen en [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) son publicadas en [Stack Overflow Talent](https://talent.stackoverflow.com).

Por el momento, no tenemos un sitio en español para publicar avisos laborales. Propuestas acá (o en `es.stackoverflow.com`) son cerradas por no ajustarse [a la temática del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Relacionados:

[¿Implementarán Trabajos para desarrolladores en SOes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2751/implementar%C3%A1n-trabajos-para-desarrolladores-en-soes)

[¿Por qué no puedo ver ofertas de trabajo en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3051/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-ver-ofertas-de-trabajo-en-el-sitio-de-stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1o)

[¿Cómo es el modelo de negocio de Stack Overflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243/c%C3%B3mo-es-el-modelo-de-negocio-de-stack-overflow)

Comment: los avisos laborales quiza se podrian compartir via chat pero no lo se